# How to properly use org.w3c.xml.Document#importNode

Tags: java, xml

Please note, SOAPHeader is extends Node and Element interfaces:

```
 Document docToAppend= getDoc();
 final SOAPHeader soapHeader = getSoapHeader();
 final Node importNode = soapHeader.getOwnerDocument().importNode(docToAppend.cloneNode(true), true);
 soapHeader.appendChild(importNode);
```

i.e. i want to append `docToAppend`to `soapHeader` node.

But it fails with exception:

> Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: The
>   implementation does not support the requested type of object or
>   operation.

I think my code is incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same error NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR.

```
DOMResult dom = new DOMResult(); 
getTransformer().transform(new StAXSource(xmlr), dom);
Node node = dom.getNode();
document.appendChild(document.importNode(node, true));  // <---- Error
```

### Cause

Found that trying to add document instead of element by checking the type of the node.

```
System.out.println("Node type is [" + dom.getNode().getNodeType() + "]");
----
Node type is [9]  <---- DOCUMENT_NODE
```

### Fix

Get the first child of the document node.

```
node = dom.getNode().getFirstChild();
System.out.println("Node type is [" + node.getNodeType() + "]");
document.appendChild(document.importNode(node, true));
----
Node type is 1 <---- ELEMENT_NODE
```

### Reference

DOCUMENT_NODE and ELEMENT_NODE values are specified in [JAVA API Constant Field Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#org.w3c).

Answer (score 1):

SOAPHeader object can have only SOAPHeaderElement objects as its immediate children.